# spork-rails in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Not loaded gem spork-rails in Rails 5, its like you can download for Rails or 5 something else to use in conjunction with a guard?

**undler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (= 5.0.0)
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.0)
    spork-rails (= 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      rails (< 5, >= 3.0.0)**

Comment: Suddenly someone will help with gem spring everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

spork-rails **(as of today)** is not supported on rails 5, and probably not needed anymore

Comment: I already knew and wrote a relevant comment on your question.